# Javascript button for Opportunity

Tags: custom-button

I need help in creating button that would prevent from creating opportunity for Inactive accounts or contacts, here is what i have so far but nothing is working

```
if('{!Account.Inactive_del__c}' == 'TRUE')
{
   alert('Opportunities cannot be created for Inactive accounts');
}
else if('{!Contact.Inactive__c}' == 'TRUE')
{
   alert('Opportunities cannot be created for Inactive contacts');
}
else
{
window.parent.location.href = "/006/e?retURL=%2F{!Account.Id}&00N40000002Gafd={!Account.Location__c}&accid={!Account.Id}&opp3={!Account.Name}" -"&conid={!Contact.Id}";
}
```

Comment: Yes  they are checkboxes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the source code, you'll see that your JS actually ends up looking like:

```
if('1' == 'TRUE')
{
   alert('Opportunities cannot be created for Inactive accounts');
}
else if('0' == 'TRUE')
{
   alert('Opportunities cannot be created for Inactive contacts');
}
else
{
window.parent.location.href = "/006/e?retURL=%2F{!Account.Id}&00N40000002Gafd={!Account.Location__c}&accid={!Account.Id}&opp3={!Account.Name}" -"&conid={!Contact.Id}";
}
```

Instead, you need to render it as a proper boolean. Here's what I came up with:

```
if( {!or(Account.Inactive__c, false)} ) {
    alert('You cannot create a new record for an inactive account.');
} else if( {!or(Contact.Inactive__c,false)} ) {
    alert('You cannot create a new record for an inactive contact.');
} else {
    window.parent.location.href = "/006/e?retURL=%2F{!Account.Id}&00N40000002Gafd={!Account.Location__c}&accid={!Account.Id}&opp3={!Account.Name}" -"&conid={!Contact.Id}";
}
```

The "OR(Field, false)" syntax forces the system to render a true or false value instead of the default blank value that it does when there's a null value (e.g. when you're using this button from the account page).

Edit: Also, you need to use "URLFOR" to prevent odd errors when a name or other value contains special characters:

```
window.top.location.href = "{!URLFOR($Action.Opportunity.New, null, ["retURL"="/"&NULLVALUE(Contact.Id, Account.Id), "00N40000002Gafd"=NULLVALUE(Contact.Name, Account.Name), "opp3"=Account.Name, "conid"=Contact.Id], true)}";
```

Comment: Thanks. Iam getting alert when it's inactive but when it's not inactive then iam getting error "You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary. For more information, see Insufficient Privileges Errors. "

Comment: @Admin_BA I've also provided an update for your URL: you need to make sure you're encoding stuff correctly. JS isn't particularly forgiving. What's the URL that you landed on?

Comment: No error but on New opp it's asking to select record type which it shouldn't and account name is not populating on opp, any idea why?

Comment: @Admin_BA If you're using record types, and there's no default, then, yes, I would expect the record type selection page to appear. It worked correctly in my org, but you're going to have to figure out how to navigate through the record type selection page or supply a default record type.

Comment: @Admin_BA To populate "account name", include `"opp4"=Account.Name, "opp4_lkid"=Account.Id` in the ULRFOR parameters.

Comment: Perfect it's populating account name and one last question how can i add "-" at the end of Opp name? right now i have "opp3"=Account.Name but i want an "-" at the end of account name, i tried "opp3"=Account.Name,"-" but it's not working

Comment: @Admin_BA In a formula, you use the normal & concatenation operator: `"opp3"=Account.Name&"-"`. If you're not familiar with it already, I'd suggest reading the [Formula Operators and Functions](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions.htm) help topic, which also broadly applies to merge fields in custom buttons and Visualforce.